# How to create Java Portlet for Tomcat server?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, portlet

We need to create Java Portlet for Tomcat server. Can we do that?

Comment: Its very much possible. What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run a portlet, you need to run it inside a Portal or Portlet container, such as [Apache JetSpeed](http://portals.apache.org/jetspeed-2/) or [Apache Pluto](http://portals.apache.org/pluto/).

Comment: But we can make it for Tomcat http://portlet-container.java.net/public/TomcatInstallation.html ?

Comment: The link http://portlet-container.java.net/public/TomcatInstallation.html does not work anymore

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned you need a Portal or Portlet Container.

You could try out [Liferay](https://www.liferay.com/downloads/liferay-portal/available-releases). They offer a Tomcat bundle and its more like a real Portal and not a test container.

Put your Portlet in the "deploy" folder and it will get registered as a portlet.